# ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token, express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf, csrf-protection

I've tried to get csurf to work but seem to have stumbled upon something. The code so far looks like this:

index.ejs

```
<form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
            .
            .
</form>
```

Where you insert password and username in the form.

app.js

```
   var express = require('express');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var profile = require('./routes/profile');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));

//Security shyts

app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter({ setOnOldIE: true }));
app.use(helmet.frameguard('deny'));
app.use(helmet.hsts({maxAge: 7776000000, includeSubdomains: true}));
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(helmet.noCache());

// rest of USE
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'anystringoftext', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, httpOnly: true, secure: true}));
app.use(csrf()); // Security, has to be after cookie and session.
app.use(flash());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/profile', profile);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
})

//app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//  var err = new Error('Not Found');
//  err.status = 404;
//  next(err);
//});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Where I've put csrf after session and cookie parser.

index.js

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'some title',message: '' });
});

router.post('/',function(req,res){
// Where I have a bunch of mysql queries to check passwords and usernames where as if they succeed they get:
res.redirect('profile');
// Else:
res.redirect('/');
 });
```

What I get after submiting the form, no matter if I insert the correct username and password or not I still get the same error:

```
invalid csrf token

403

ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
```

Also I want add that I've been working with node for about 2 weeks, so there is still alot I need to learn probably.

Comment: Are your routes being setup before or after the csurf middleware? It would help if you showed the complete code...

Comment: Guess I could print out the whole app.js part.

Done!

Comment: Silly question, but you are definitely binding the token to the form? I don't see that happening anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`{{csrfToken}}` isn't an EJS construction, so it's not expanded at all and is probably sent literally to your server.

This should work better:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
```

The middleware is setting `csrftoken` though, with lowercase 't', where the template expects an uppercase 'T':

```
res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken(); // change to `res.locals.csrfToken`
```

You also generate two different tokens, which is probably not what you want. Store the token in a variable and reuse that:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.csrfToken();
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;
  next();
});
```

And lastly, you probably have to move your middleware to before the route declarations, otherwise it won't be called:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.csrfToken();
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;
  next();
});
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/profile', profile);
```

Comment: I'll try and report back!

Comment: No errors and everything worked! I'll proceed and read up on more specifics around how tokens gets passed and so on. I however bow down and than you!

Comment: why you say he generates the token twice? he creates one, and assigns it two times
var token = req.csrfToken();
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
  res.locals.csrfToken = token;

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni if you look at the code in the original question, you'll see that it calls `req.csrfToken()` twice. The code I posted (which you're referring to) is a possible solution for that issue.

Comment: sorry @robertklep

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni no worries :D I edited my answer because it wasn't really clear that I meant the code to be a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My Express version is **6.14.4**. The most important matter is you have to maintain the order of the line.
App.js

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//order of bellow lins is very important
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }))
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/user/signup', function(req, res, next){
  console.log("csruf: "+req.csrfToken());
  res.render('user/signup', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});

router.post('/postuser', function(req, res, next){
 //res.render('/');
 res.redirect('/');
});
```

view file

```
 <form action="/postuser"  method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email"> E-Mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue, because I Have not included following middleware. It worked well after that.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```