# Getting ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token with multer added locally to image upload router

Tags: node.js, express, security, csrf, multer

I am using csurf as recommended in my Express application to guard against cross sites forgeries. I have registered it globally(illustrated with code below) and so far so good.

Now, I have added multer.js to be able to upload images and as their documentation recommends it, it's more secure to attach multer to each express route where you intend to use.

Now when I do attach multer to my upload routes, I am faced with a 'ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token' and I really don't know why, as my view I am submitting the form from, as a csrf token attached to it.

Below is my code and I would really appreciated any help/suggestions. Thank you all

### app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const csrf = require('csurf');
const csrfProtection = csrf();
const shopRoute = require('../Routes/shop');
const app = express();

app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use(shopRoutes);
```

### routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');
const controllers = require('../Controllers/shop');

router.post('/upload', multer({storage: multer.memoryStorage(), fileFilter: fileFilter), controller.uploadFunction);
```

Comment: did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893794/forbiddenerror-invalid-csrf-token-express-js) ?

Comment: @boolfalse thank you for the reference, however, that case isn't similar to the one I am experiencing. csrf works perfectly in my app, it only became a problem when I added multer.js to the route I built for image upload. As soon as I remove multer as I showed in the code above, it works perfectly. Do you have any idea why is that? Is multer throwing an error which triggers csrf token invalid error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that when you are uploading a file, the content type of the request becomes `multipart/form-data`, and you cannot simply pass the csrf token to Express in the body anymore.

The API allows to pass it in the URL though. Try passing the token in the `_csrf` parameter, that I think should solve your issue. So simply post the form to `.../?_csrf={your_token}`. Note though that this is slightly less secure than passing your csrf token in the request body, and might be flagged as a potential vulnerability in later penetration tests if you ever have one.

Alternatively, for a little more security, you can also pass it as a request header, but that might be a little trickier on the client side. According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html), Express will take the token from the following:

```
req.body._csrf - typically generated by the body-parser module.
req.query._csrf - a built-in from Express.js to read from the URL query string.
req.headers['csrf-token'] - the CSRF-Token HTTP request header.
req.headers['xsrf-token'] - the XSRF-Token HTTP request header.
req.headers['x-csrf-token'] - the X-CSRF-Token HTTP request header.
req.headers['x-xsrf-token'] - the X-XSRF-Token HTTP request header.
```

So adding a `csrf-token` header should also work.

Disclaimer: I don't know multer.js at all, and have very little experience with Express.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I am currently traveling and will be applying your suggestion as soon as I can. Hopefully one of the different ways to send the token back to the server will fix it.